# Jabber and expensive data (xml its trash)

Tags: compression, xmpp

Im working in a project that has jabber has communication platform.

The thing is that i need clients (a lot of clients) to communicate between each other not only for signalization, but to change data between them.

Imagine that the client A has 3 services available. The client B could request to A to start sending him info from each service (like a stream service) until the client B says to A to stop the services.

These services could only send one character with 100ms interval or 1000characters with 100ms interval or even send some data when its needed.

When the info sended to B, arrives it has to know what service corresponds, what action and the values (example), so im using json over jabber.

My problem is that im wasting a lot of bandwith with jabber xmpp protocol just to send a message with a body like:

{"s":"x", "x":5} //each 100ms (5 represents any number)

I really don't want to have parallel communication (like direct sockets), because jabber has all of that implemented and its easy scalable, firewall problems, sometimes i use http communications (im using BOSH in this case).

I know that there is some compression that i can do, but im wondering if you recommends something else that could not have such ammount of xml behind my message and still, using jabber.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best Regards,

Eduardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like, except for your significant data transfer, XMPP suits your application well.

As you probably know, XMPP was never designed or intended to be used as a big pipe for data transfer. Most applications that involve significant data transfer, such as file transfers and voice/video, use XMPP just for negotiation of a separate "out of band" stream. You say this might cause problems for you because of firewalls and web clients.

If your application is mostly transferring text, then you really should try out compression... it offers significant savings on bandwidth, if that's your most constrained resource. The downside is that it will take more client and server memory (around 300KB by default, but that can be reduced with marginal compression loss).

Alternatively you can look at tunneling your data base64-encoded using [In-Band Bytestreams](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0047.html). I don't have your sample data, or know how you are wrapping them for transport, and this could come off worse or better. I would say it would come off better if you stripped out your JSON and made it into a more efficient binary format instead. Base64 data will not compress so well, and is roughly 33% larger than the raw data. The savings would be in being able to strip out JSON and any other extraneous wrappings, while keeping the data within the XMPP stream.

In the end scaling most applications is hard, whichever technologies you use. It requires primarily insight - you shouldn't change anything without testing it first, and you should be testing beforehand to find out what you ought to change. You should be analyzing your system for the primary bottlenecks (is it really the client's bandwidth??). Rarely in my experience has XML itself been the direct bottleneck. However ultimately all these things are unique to your application, it's not easy to give generic advice at scale.

Comment: By the way, I should have added when talking about binary protocols that Google's Protocol Buffers is a much better start than designing your own format from scratch. When you have a fixed data schema they can be much more compact than JSON and XML: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/

Answer (score 2):

No, Xml is no trash. Its human readable, very extensible and can be compressed extremely well.

XMPP supports stream compression, and this stream compression (mostly zlib) works extremely well according to all my tests. So if its important for you that you optimize the number of bytes you send over the wire or are on low bandwidth then use stream compression when you are on sockets. When you are on Bosh then you have to use either a server which supports HTTP compression or use a proxy in between to enable compression. But keep in mind that BOSH has also lots of overhead with all the HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was saying that xml is trash not the xml itself, but the quantity of xml that is behind the xmpp message.

Comment: The compression mechanism is described here: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0138.html.  Make sure to test to make sure that the CPU overhead of compressing doesn't make your problem worse.